# How I can listen for a tcp port in kernel space (freebsd)?

Tags: sockets, tcp, kernel, freebsd

As the title says, How I can work with tcp sockets in kernel space?
Is there any tricky notes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [a post](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7660?page=0,2) on linuxjournal.com about networking in kernel.

May be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Look at ng_ksocket. Even if you will not use netgraph, it is a nice implementation of kernel-level socket manipulation.